# My android app detected as malware

Tags: android, root, busybox

I am using an open source  library in my app to check whether the user has root access or busybox installed on his android device.

The link below is the library link:

https://github.com/Stericson/RootShell

I implemented in the last update  a terminal emulator shell section , to help the  user execute root commands directly.
My app is now detected as a thread and malware by some antiviruses.
after trying many times to fix the bug I didn't find a solution,
but after reading many time the code I think that that 3 lines of codes are causing that alert:

```
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectAll().penaltyLog().build());
```

Is strict mode causing that alert?

Comment: I don't know whether strictMode is the cause, but you should only use strictMode when developing, not in production. Read more https://blog.mindorks.com/use-strictmode-to-find-things-you-did-by-accident-in-android-development-4cf0e7c8d997#.6al3zds4t

Comment: The point is that Checking or Using Root is mostly used by Maleware. With that in mind most of the AV Solutions on Android don't really care and cause a alert. That's mostly because most(if not all) Antivirus Solution on Android can't compete with PC versions and their Logic is rather dumb

Comment: I had situation, when my application used NDK to encrypt some data, and that was enough to some antivirus apps to detect my application as malware

Comment: But If you downlad an app , and app is detected as virus by certain antivirus , did you keep or simply uninstall the app ?? many users uninstalled my app due to this false alert.

Comment: I almost sure that's all because of that library. Try to figure out how it works, maybe u will need author's assistance, or replace it with another lib.

Comment: ouff , I am using many open source licenses in my app ? maybe the false alert is from safety net helper